# How to add more values to a TreeNode class in C#

Tags: c#, treeview

A TreeNode class has

Text   Name    Tag

I need to assign more values to a TreeNode class like float1, float2, ... float6.

How can I do this??? pls help.

Thx,
Caslav

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a new class which inherits the TreeNode.
For each value you want to store in the treenode, create a property for that value. 
When working with the Treeview, simply cast the TreeNode to your custom TreeNode class.

**Example:**

```
public class JobTreeNode : TreeNode {

    private int intField1;

    public int Field1 {
        get {
            return intField1;
        }
        set {
            intField1 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage** (added after comments)

```
// Add the node
JobTreeNode CustomNode = new JobTreeNode();
CustomNode.Text = "Test";
CustomNode.Field1 = 10
treeView1.Nodes.add(CustomNode);


// SelectedNode 
((CustomNode)(treeView1.SelectedNode)).Field1;
```

Comment: I tried that but I cannot display values in textbox when I select node.
Example:

textbox1.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Name.ToString();  <-- works
textbox2.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.IntField or IntField1.ToString();   <-- doesn`t work

Comment: You have to cast the SelectedNode.

Something like this: ((CustomNode)(treeView1.SelectedNode)).Field1;

Comment: You also have to make sure you _Add_ JobTreeNode elements.

Comment: Thank you very VERY much... The casting was the problem.

Now it works like a charm!!

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

The Tag property of TreeNode is "object". Can't you just store your data in there using a dataclass of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a lightweight class to hold your float1..6 and put an instance in the Tag property.

Alternatively, you can use a `Dictionary<TreeNode, FloatsClass>` or maybe use 6 separate `Dictionary<TreeNode, float>`.

Note that dotNet 4 has a new `Tuple<A,B,C,...>` type to make this kind of situations a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could have:

```
class TreeNodeProperties
{
  public float Float1 { get; set;}
  public float Float2 { get; set;}
  public float Float3 { get; set;}
  public float Float4 { get; set;}
  public float Float5 { get; set;}
  public float Float6 { get; set;}
}
```

Then set the Tag property on your TreeNode:

```
var properties = new TreeNodeProperties()
{
  Float1 = 10,
  Float2 = 20,
  Float3 = 30,
  Float4 = 40,
  Float5 = 50,
  Float6 = 60
}
myTreeNode.Tag = properties;
```

To read the properties:

```
var nodeproperties = TreeViewMyTree.SelectedNode.Tag as TreeNodeProperties;
MessageBox.Show("Float5: "+nodeproperties.Float5);
```